# What is difference between callback function and regular function?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, callback, calling-convention

Ok I'll give two examples of function is using `CALLBACK` and regular function.
*Note:  I didn't write these examples.*

Regular Function

```
int sumExample (int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
int main()
{
     int = sumExample(1, 3);
     cout  >> int;
     return 0;
}
```

Function using _stdcall

```
int __stdcall sumExample (int a, int b);
```

what is the difference?
*Note:  I'm not sure how Calling Conventions works, an example would help!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, a calling convention specifies implementation details of how the function will be called. Most libraries use the Standard C calling convention - `__cdecl`. WinAPI however expects `__stdcall`. You only need to know two things about calling conventions: that they have to match, e.g., you can't convert a `void(*)(int, int)`, which is implicitly a `void(__cdecl *)(int, int)`, to a `void(__stdcall *)(int, int)`, and that the default is `__cdecl`. `CALLBACK` is just a WinAPI #define so that they can change if they want to.

Comment: Well, they can't change CALLBACK because that would break all programs, but what they can do is #ifdef it to mean something else on some other platform (e.g. Alpha, MIPS etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Not much, really. A "callback" is a name given to a function to be passed to another function that will "call it back" when... something useful happens. There's no reason it can't also be used as a regular function though.

Answer (score 0):

**A callback is a function pointer (i.e. address) that is passed to another piece of code.**

The address of the callback function is passed to a normal function.

This allows a lower-level software layer to call a function defined in a higher-level layer.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)